# Creating Live Wallpapers in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, renderscript

I am interested in a custom live wallpaper for android but am confused on what most people use to create them. I was looking at openGL and saw some nice tutorials.. but basically what I have in mind is being able to use a real picture, and play around with different layers to edit the sky for day time vs night time. Can this be done using openGL?  If not what are some other techniques used in creating live wallpapers? It seems the internet's current tutorial are vague or just a tutorial on getting started. I would like help on how to actually design the background and make updates to it during run-time.

This link here:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-live-wallpapers-on-android--mobile-9516

demonstrates the core of creating the live wallpaper, which also references this link here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-renderscript-on-android--mobile-9154

which uses renderscript to create the graphic. For those who currently or have had experience with live wallpapers, will renderscript allow me to interact with the code in real time? Or does the android code just run the script and that's all?